# Insert checking in another table if value exists

Tags: postgresql, join, query

My problem is the following:
I have 2 Tables T1(idName) and T2(idName, name).
I need to do an Insert in T1 with only the name and that the query compares if the name exists in T2 and get the idName to insert that value in T1.
I have not tried anything yet because I have not found how to do it.

Comment: Please don't tag for multiple DBMSes, but rather only for the one you are actually using.

Comment: Do you already know how to find an `idName` in `T2` when you are given a name? Just to find, without inserting the result anywhere. If you do, from that point it would be just one small step towards getting the insert statement.